# How to get uncommon natural weapons?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, natural-weapon

I'm interested in ways how to get more [natural attacks](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/rules-for-monsters/universal-monster-rules/#Natural_Attacks) on a player character.

Not interested in Claws and Bite since those are common and relatively easy to acquire.

Wings are also relatively easy with the [Powerful Wings](https://aonprd.com/FeatDisplay.aspx?ItemName=Powerful%20Wings) feat.

For gore attack I found [Spirit Oni Master](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/general-feats/spirit-oni-master/), but there might be other ways.

Mainly interested in the uncommon ones such as hooves, talons, tentacles, pincers, tail slap, slam and sting to add them to my full attack (Lashing Tail is useless for instance).

EDIT: Out campaign is limited to Paizo materials.

Comment: @enumag Do you have other requirements, such as race, class, or at what level you'll acquire these attacks?

Comment: @BenS. Not really, I'm just theory crafting at this point and want to know my options.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are several grafts available among the [Demonic Implants](https://www.aonprd.com/MagicDemonicImplants.aspx), [Necrografts](https://www.aonprd.com/Necrografts.aspx), and [Fleshcrafting](https://www.aonprd.com/MagicFleshcrafting.aspx) options.

---

**Bite**

- Poison Fang ([Fleshcrafting](https://www.aonprd.com/MagicFleshcrafting.aspx))
- [Animal Mask](https://www.aonprd.com/MagicWondrousDisplay.aspx?FinalName=Animal%20Mask) item
- [Cloak of Fangs](https://www.aonprd.com/MagicWondrousDisplay.aspx?FinalName=Cloak%20of%20Fangs) item
- [Mouthpiece of the Dominion](https://www.aonprd.com/MagicWondrousDisplay.aspx?FinalName=Mouthpiece%20of%20the%20Dominion) item
- [Ophidian Coil](https://www.aonprd.com/MagicRingsDisplay.aspx?FinalName=Ophidian%20Coil) item
- [Ring of Rat Fangs](https://www.aonprd.com/MagicRingsDisplay.aspx?FinalName=Ring%20of%20Rat%20Fangs)
- [Razortusk](https://www.aonprd.com/FeatDisplay.aspx?ItemName=Razortusk) feat (Orcs)
- [Sharptooth](https://www.aonprd.com/FeatDisplay.aspx?ItemName=Sharptooth) feat (Ratfolk)
- [Unusual Heritage](https://www.aonprd.com/FeatDisplay.aspx?ItemName=Unusual%20Heritage%20(Dhampir)) feat (Dhampir)
- [Tusked](https://www.aonprd.com/TraitDisplay.aspx?ItemName=Tusked) trait (Orc, Half-Orc)
- [Mother's Teeth](https://www.aonprd.com/TraitDisplay.aspx?ItemName=Mother%27s%20Teeth) trait (Goblin)
- and several other race feats or (alternate) racial traits (usually for Orcs, Half-Orcs, Goblins/Goblinoids, Tieflings, Aasimar, Catfolk, Skinwalkers, Ratfolk, Tengu, Kitsune)

---

**Claw**

- Burrowing Claws ([Fleshcrafting](https://www.aonprd.com/MagicFleshcrafting.aspx))
- Retractable Spines ([Fleshcrafting](https://www.aonprd.com/MagicFleshcrafting.aspx))
- [Aspect of the Beast](https://www.aonprd.com/FeatDisplay.aspx?ItemName=Aspect%20of%20the%20Beast) feat

---

**Gore**

- Crown of Horns ([Demonic Implant](https://www.aonprd.com/MagicDemonicImplants.aspx))
- [Deadly Horns](https://www.aonprd.com/FeatDisplay.aspx?ItemName=Deadly%20Horns) feat
- [Animal Mask](https://www.aonprd.com/MagicWondrousDisplay.aspx?FinalName=Animal%20Mask) item
- [Healm of the Mammoth Lord](https://www.aonprd.com/MagicWondrousDisplay.aspx?FinalName=Helm%20of%20the%20Mammoth%20Lord) item
- [Greathelm of the Mammoth Lord](https://www.aonprd.com/MagicWondrousDisplay.aspx?FinalName=Greathelm%20of%20the%20Mammoth%20Lord) item

---

**Hoof**

- Brazen Hooves ([Demonic Implant](https://www.aonprd.com/MagicDemonicImplants.aspx))

---

**Slam**

- Necrograft Arm ([Necrograft](https://www.aonprd.com/Necrografts.aspx))
- [Chaos Reigns](https://www.aonprd.com/FeatDisplay.aspx?ItemName=Chaos%20Reigns) feat
- Fiendish Obedience (Sentinel) for [Kostchtchie](https://www.aonprd.com/DeityDisplay.aspx?ItemName=Kostchtchie)

---

**Sting**

- Stinging Tail ([Fleshcrafting](https://www.aonprd.com/MagicFleshcrafting.aspx))
- [Fleshwarped Scorpion's Tail](https://www.aonprd.com/MagicWeaponsDisplay.aspx?ItemName=Fleshwarped%20Scorpion%27s%20Tail) item
- [Wyvern Cloak](https://www.aonprd.com/MagicWondrousDisplay.aspx?FinalName=Wyvern%20Cloak) item

---

**Tail**

- [Cloak of the Manta Ray](https://www.aonprd.com/MagicWondrousDisplay.aspx?FinalName=Cloak%20of%20the%20Manta%20Ray) item
- [Tail Strike](https://www.aonprd.com/SpellDisplay.aspx?ItemName=Tail%20Strike) spell
- [Gelugon Armor](https://www.aonprd.com/MagicArmorDisplay.aspx?ItemName=Gelugon%20Armor) item

---

**Talon**

- Demon Talon ([Demonic Implant](https://www.aonprd.com/MagicDemonicImplants.aspx)) (RAW a claw attack)
- [Talons of Leng](https://www.aonprd.com/MagicWondrousDisplay.aspx?FinalName=Talons%20of%20Leng) item (RAW a claw attack)

---

**Tentacle**

- Grasping Tendril ([Fleshcrafting](https://www.aonprd.com/MagicFleshcrafting.aspx))
- [Tentacle Cloak](https://www.aonprd.com/MagicWondrousDisplay.aspx?FinalName=Tentacle%20Cloak) item

---

**Wing**

- [Dread Wing](https://www.aonprd.com/MagicArmorDisplay.aspx?ItemName=Dread%20Wing) armor quality
- [Powerful Wings](https://www.aonprd.com/FeatDisplay.aspx?ItemName=Powerful%20Wings) feat (requires natural wings)
- [Metallic Wings](https://www.aonprd.com/FeatDisplay.aspx?ItemName=Metallic%20Wings) feat (Aasimar)
- [Mighty Boughs](https://www.aonprd.com/FeatDisplay.aspx?ItemName=Mighty%20Boughs) feat (Gathlain)

---

**Others/Several**

- [Mutated Shape](https://www.aonprd.com/FeatDisplay.aspx?ItemName=Mutated%20Shape) feat (Wildshape)
- [Beaststrike Club](https://www.aonprd.com/MagicWeaponsDisplay.aspx?ItemName=Beaststrike%20Club) item
- dozens of Polymorph spells like [Monstrous Extremities](https://www.aonprd.com/SpellDisplay.aspx?ItemName=Monstrous%20Extremities), [Ooze Form](https://www.aonprd.com/SpellDisplay.aspx?ItemName=Ooze%20Form%20I) or [Undead Anatomy](https://www.aonprd.com/SpellDisplay.aspx?ItemName=Undead%20Anatomy%20I), as well as other magic abilities
- a ton of class features and archetypes, from Alchemist Discoveries (Feral, Tentacle) and Barbarian Rage Powers (Totem of the Fiend) Oracle Curses & Revelations – too many to list
- of those class features, the Sorcerer's bloodline powers (e.g. [Draconic Claws](https://www.aonprd.com/BloodlineDisplay.aspx?ItemName=Draconic), [Salamander's Tail](https://www.aonprd.com/BloodlineDisplay.aspx?ItemName=Salamander), or [Serpentine's Fang](https://www.aonprd.com/BloodlineDisplay.aspx?ItemName=Serpentine)) can be accessed class-neutral via the [Improved Eldritch Heritage](https://www.aonprd.com/FeatDisplay.aspx?ItemName=Improved%20Eldritch%20Heritage) feat.

I couldn't find any Pincers.

Comment: That's a great list with many options I wasn't aware of. Thanks!

Comment: Note: Salamander's Tail doesn't work with Eldritch Heritage since it's not a 1st level power.

Comment: Note: Gelugon Armor doesn't seem to work as part of a full attack.

Comment: True, Gelugon Armor won't work as part of a full attack.
Salamander's Tail can be accessed via Improved Eldritch Heritage, not the base Eldritch Heritage!